# selecting a column from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
TABLE 1
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| uid | color | brand | model |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  10 |     1 |     2 |     1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+

TABLE 2
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| uid | quantity |model |color|
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  25 |     2 |     2 |     1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

I have many tables like this where the **uid** column is present in every table.I have a value in a variable, say var1=25. I want to check whether var1 value matches with any of the uid value of any table.If it matches I want to print the table name. Can anyone help me with this?

I tried doing this and I found

```
   SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
   FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
   WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
   AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

But this is not giving what I want since I want to select all the tables in a database irrespective of the table name.If in future any table is added then it should also get selected.

Answer (score 0):

At first, `information_schema` table doesn't have specific tuple data.
I suggest you to consider different design.

A. Make a meta table and use triggers(attached to base tables) to maintain meta table.

```
CREATE TABLE meta_table (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  uid INT,
  table_name VARCHAR(50)
);

# When you need to add new table (table 3)
CREATE TABLE table_3 (
  uid INT,
  field1 INT,
  field2 INT,
  field3
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER table_3_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON table_3
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO meta_table (uid, table_name)
    VALUE (NEW.uid, "table_3");

END$$
DELIMITER ;

# If data in `table_3` might be changed or deleted,
# then create trigger for `delete` and `update`
```

B. Use only one table with unstructured field and parse `data` field in your application

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  uid INT,
  table_type INT,
  data VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO table (10, 1, '{"color":1,"brand":2,"model":1}');
INSERT INTO table (10, 2, '{"quantity":2,"model":2,"color":1}');
```

As you mentioned "any table can be added" often, I strongly recommend B solution. It is not good design that changing schema(creating table) often.

Comment: And other various solution can be considered if sam specify your situation more.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant.What I want I have written clearly in question. Please help me in understanding how to achieve it?

Comment: Answer edited with adding more explanation and comment.